# Thermistor failure AC air handler fan

Tags: hvac

Modern air handlers (the indoor portion of an AC/heat pump system) have a variable speed motor in two parts: the motor itself and an ECM "module", a computerized motor controller.  They are viciously expensive to replace.

According to do-it-yourselfers and Youtubes starring guys in HVAC uniforms, the most common failure of ECMs is the thermistor, a five-dollar part. Every one of those videos, without exception, show an exploded component (lookes like a capacitor the size of nickel), and burns on the bottom of the circuit board.

Is is possible or normal for a thermistor to fail with no outward signs?  Based on the relative costs, I will probably replace the thermistor before buying a completely new ECM.

Comment: Ok lets make sure we are thinking of the same components. A thermistor is a resistive device that the resistance varies with temperature usually smaller than a pea but larger than a grain of rice. The part I see go bad about the size of a nickel and up to a quarter is a mov metal oxide varistor. These dump voltage to ground  at a set voltage threshold (they protect the drive electronics from inductive kickback ) voltage spikes. A mov usually has evidence of heating up sometimes very small in some cases not visible.

Comment: Mouser describes the SG348 as an Ametherm "Inrush Current Limiter", a subspecies of thermistor. They no longer stock this component. The manufacturer no longer publishes specs. Mouser provided a spec sheet for another device (no telling whether accidentally or on purpose), the SG170, which is one ohm at 25 degrees and Imax of 8A.  The logical replacement would be the SG379, also one ohm at 25 degrees, but an Imax 30A.

Comment: MOV's do not limit current in fact they have a very limited ability to handle current but they do limit voltage spikes their main failure cause is because the current was above there ability to dump the excess voltage to ground. To make it clearer once the voltage threshold is reached they are like a switch they start conducting the spike in voltage to ground they can dump thousands of volts but once the current exceeds there wattage they go up in smoke just like a wire that is connected to ground it fails because of excess current not from excess voltage. Thermistors are variable resistors.

Comment: To long continued, a thermistor is much smaller than an MOV and they have NO current handling capability most are not much larger than 2-3 grains of rice and almost always smaller than a pea ok I have never seen one as large as a pea. These if used are to detect a change in voltage across a resistor and that change is based on temperature not current. I am not only a electrician but have a degree in electronics plus have worked on HVAC equipment for years, I have replaced hundreds of MOV's but maybe only a dozen Thermistors, a thermistor has a specific resistance that changes with temperature

Comment: It's probably worthwhile to continue the discussion, then publish an answer when we have consensus.  I believe that I have conclusively identified the component in question, even if it has a different form factor than you predict. Insofar as replacing an ECM motor module is expensive, an authoritative answer would help all the readers.

Comment: Without the model of the motor I can't look up the parts list, there are some Thermistors used in the control electronics of some motors I looked up, to test a thermister put your ohm meter on the leads and warm it with a hair dryer, if the resistance changes it is probably good. There are all kinds of ranges based on different types positive coefficient will start at a low value and increase the resistance when heated. A negative coefficent will start at a higher value and drop when heated. Although I have not seen one that big that will be a method to test as it may be for the motor control

Comment: An "Inrush Current Limiter" is a thermistor with the negative temperature coefficient (NTC) you described and described [here](http://vlab.amrita.edu/?sub=1&brch=282&sim=1511&cnt=1).